# @viewchild unable to get input element value from child component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-components, viewchild

I am using parent and child component. In child component I use search box. I need to get search box value at any time on demand. How to get this?

Child Component html - GridViewComponent

```
<input id="successFilter" name='filterInput' type="text" (keyup)="searchSuccess($event)">
```

Parent Component ts

```
@ViewChild(GridviewComponent) grdView: GridviewComponent;
```

wrote above line before constructor

```
this.grdView.filterInput.subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

am unable to get input value on demand

Comment: This is before constructor @ViewChild(GridviewComponent) grdView: GridviewComponent;

Answer (score 2):

GridView html

```
<input id="successFilter" name='filterInput' [(ngModel)]="filterInput" type="text" (keyup)="searchSuccess($event)">
```

GridView typescript

```
import { Output, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-gridView',
  templateUrl: './gridView.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./gridView.component.scss']
})
export class GridViewComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() sendValue = new EventEmitter<string>();
   filterInput = '';

   constructor(){}

   ngOnInit() {}

  getValue() {
      this.sendValue.emit(this.filterInput);
  }
}
```

ParentComponent typescript, call getChildValue() whenever you need to get the value

```
@ViewChild('gridView') grdView;

getChildValue() {
   this.grdView.getValue();
}

receivedValue(theValue: string) {
   //this is where you actually get theValue
}
```

ParentComponent html

```
<app-gridView #gridView (sendValue)="receivedValue($event)"></app-gridView>
```

Comment: Thank you. Will this work any time not only text change also at normal time ?  me check and revert back to you

Comment: If you want to get it anytime your text changes you can make your (keyup) function be (keyup)="getValue()"

Comment: Kevin, I'm able to get value using the method, thanks for your help